# Get value of one column based on another column in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is what I am trying to do: Get all people with the same boss and email the boss. I can only use the table below and I would like to add another column showing the boss email which is found in the table.

```
id      name       email            boss     
-------------------------------------------
1       Apple      Apple@alo.com    Rita    
2       Bob        Bob@alo.com      Rita    
3       Charlie    Charlie@alo.com  Nuna      
4       Dan        Dan@alo.com      Rita   
5       Rita       Rita@alo.com     Sheeba    
6       Nuna       Nuna@alo.com     Sheeba
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried selfjoining the table?

Comment: I attempted to do a subquery but I did not do selfjoining (thanks, @Hogan for making the distinction between the two concepts)

Comment: More like joining the table to itself like the answer of Hogan

Comment: a join is not a subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a join to do that.  It looks like the code below.  When joining to the same table you have to use an alias.

```
SELECT base.name, boss.email as boss_email
from the_table_name_you_did_not_say as base
join the_table_name_you_did_not_say as boss on base.boss = boss.name
```

> Technically you don't have to use an alias on the base table if you select a wildcard `*` for some platforms